# Can't run Jenkins Build - bundle: "command not found"

Tags: ruby, cucumber, jenkins, bundler

I am currently trying to run a jenkins build for some of my cucumber tasks. All of my gems have been installed by using the Bundler. The gems are stored in the vendor folder.

However, when I try and run `bundle install --deployment` in the execute shell build step, I get the following error:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/cukes/workspace
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000004000001/T/hudson4461284045505361460.sh
+ bundle install --deployment
/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000004000001/T/hudson4461284045505361460.sh: line 2: bundle: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

This is driving me crazy! It runs on my local machine with no problems. Why can't Jenkins see my gems?

Any help would be great!

Cheers,
Jon

Answer (score 17):

In my case, I added this line to the first of script:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
```

Comment: Worked but why ? :-)

Comment: @SahilRally I don't know. 
if you got the answer, please let me know :-)

Comment: @RezaDehnavi in the manual it says `-l` "makes bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell".  So it worked for OP in the local machine so after adding it makes it works in jenkins also

Answer (score 12):

Depending on the way you installed Jenkins, it might be running as a separate user, typically as user `jenkins`. If you have installed `bundle` into a nonstandard directory which isn't in the default PATH, like `/usr/local/bin`, you need to:

- Add `/usr/local/bin` to the PATH of the jenkins user (check ~jenkins/.bashrc) or
- Configure PATH environment variable in Jenkins global configuration (or slave configuration if building on a slave) or
- Modify the build script to refer to `bundle` using a full path name.

Comment: Hi, i added /bin/bash instead /usr/bin/bash was not available. I am using centos.

Answer (score 3):

If bundle is installed in `/usr/local/bin/bundle` (determine this with `which bundle`) you could just add a symbolic link to bundle in `/usr/bin` like so:

`ln -s /usr/local/bin/bundle /usr/bin/bundle`

Answer (score 2):

First things to verify:

- Make sure `bundle` is installed on the machine where Jenkins runs.
- If it installed, make sure it's on the path for the user under which Jenkins runs

(To verify path/environment: insert shell build step that runs `env`)

Answer (score 1):

For me I had originally installed it via the war file as that's the way recommended on the [Getting Started Guide](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/getting-started/). However, the user handbook makes it much more clear that there are probably better ways to [install Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/).

I ended up uninstalling the WAR file of Jenkins on macOS by:

1. Deleting the .war file.
2. Deleting the ~/.jenkins directory.

I then [reinstalled via home-brew](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#macos), and `bundle` started working.

Answer (score 0):

You could see where is `bundle` is installed by running `which bundle` and run the `bundle` command from there