# RVM/Ruby/Bundle/Cucumber not working on Jenkins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jenkins, cucumber, rvm

When I try to run my cucumber scripts (or RVM/Ruby/Bundle) on Jenkins, I get the following error (command not found):

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Testing/workspace
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/hudson6097735085503119949.sh
+ cucumber features/scheduling/scheduling_nonlive/schedule_page.feature --line 4 --format json -o cucumber.json
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/hudson6097735085503119949.sh: line 2: cucumber: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

After Googling, I'm fairly confident is has to do with some RVM and PATH/permissions problems from Jenkins. How do I change the PATH so Jenkins can use the same PATH that I use?

```
~% which cucumber
/Users/fyousuf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/cucumber

~/.jenkins% pwd
/Users/fyousuf/.jenkins

~/.jenkins% which rvm
/Users/fyousuf/.rvm/bin/rvm

~/.jenkins% which ruby
/Users/fyousuf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
```

My ~/.bashrc contains:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

My .bash_profile:

```
 PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/jruby-1.7.5/bin:$PATH
 [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Has anyone run into a similar issue and knew how to solve it?

Answer (score -1):

use this path for `cucumber`:

```
/Users/fyousuf/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247/cucumber
```

Comment: Where should I put that?

Comment: Also it's not just Cucumber that doesn't work, other things like "rvm list" or "bundle" don't work, "ruby -v" gives a different version of Ruby than my dev env.

Comment: you use `sh` shell which is not supported by rvm, try instead `/bin/bash -l /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/hudson6097735085503119949.sh` or show the script that gets run.

Comment: for the ruby installation, try rerunning it, and for the script - I need to see it, without seeing it it's hard to tell how to fix it

Comment: Hmmm...I'm thinking the solution has to do with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209242/rvm-and-jenkins-setup or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365792/cant-run-jenkins-build-bundle-command-not-found, but not sure what to change in my environment....